# How to export packages and classes to a test module in a Java app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I want to build a multi-modules SpringBoot app with following modules :

- **App** : the Parent module, Main class is here
- **Model** : all Domain objects, no Main class, no tests
- **Tests** : dedicated to whole app tests, will have Cucumber tests

My problem is :

I actually can run unit tests on **Model**'s objects in **Tests** module, but doing a `mvn clean install` on **App** module fails because **Tests** module doesn't know anything about **Model**'s objects.

- In one hand, **Spring** makes the job, importing all needed classes
  from **Model** module and running tests on them.
- In the other hand, **Maven** cries with the following error :
  `package com.my-app.model.my-package does not exist`.

OK, Spring and Maven are 2 different tools but what should I do in the App's POM to explicitely declare that all objects from the Model module should be exported to Tests module in order to be tested ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.humanresources.game</groupId>
    <artifactId>hrg-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Application</name>
    <description>Human Resources game engine</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>../hrg-model</module>
        <module>../hrg-tests</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <mainClass>HrgAppApplication</mainClass>
                    <goal>package</goal>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The **Tests**' module POM only declares a `<dependency>` block on **Model** Module.

Neither **Tests** module nor **Model** one have any `<build>` block in their respective POM.

As seen [here](https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-multimodule), everything should only be managed by **App**'s POM.

So my question is : what should I add in the **App**'s POM `<build>` block to effectively export all **Model**'s packages and classes to **Tests** module so that it remains possible to `mvn clean install` the whole project ?

Thanx by advance.

Edit : POM.xml for Tests and Model modules

**Tests / POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.humanresources.game</groupId>
        <artifactId>hrg-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../hrg-app/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>hrg-tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Tests</name>
    <description>Tests project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.humanresources.game</groupId>
            <artifactId>hrg-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Model / POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.humanresources.game</groupId>
        <artifactId>hrg-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../hrg-app/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>hrg-model</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Model</name>
    <description>Tests project for Human Resources game</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**Console Output after `mvn clean install` (unit test succeeds though) :**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Application                                                        [pom]
[INFO] Model                                                              [jar]
[INFO] Tests                                                              [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.humanresources.game:hrg-app >-------------------
[INFO] Building Application 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                  [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ hrg-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ hrg-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ hrg-app ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-app\pom.xml to C:\Users\Fred\.m2\repository\com\humanresources\game\hrg-app\1.0-SNAPSHOT\hrg-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.humanresources.game:hrg-model >------------------
[INFO] Building Model 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                      [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-model\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-model\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-model\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-model\target\hrg-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-model\target\hrg-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Fred\.m2\repository\com\humanresources\game\hrg-model\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\hrg-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-model\pom.xml to C:\Users\Fred\.m2\repository\com\humanresources\game\hrg-model\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\hrg-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.humanresources.game:hrg-tests >------------------
[INFO] Building Tests 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                      [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ hrg-tests ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-tests\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ hrg-tests ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ hrg-tests ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-tests\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ hrg-tests ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-tests\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hrg-tests ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Fred\IdeaProjects\HumanResources\hrg-tests\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Fred/IdeaProjects/HumanResources/hrg-tests/src/test/java/com/humanresources/game/hrgtests/HrgTestsApplicationTests.java:[3,42] package com.humanresources.game.model.card does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Fred/IdeaProjects/HumanResources/hrg-tests/src/test/java/com/humanresources/game/hrgtests/HrgTestsApplicationTests.java:[4,47] package com.humanresources.game.model.territory does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Fred/IdeaProjects/HumanResources/hrg-tests/src/test/java/com/humanresources/game/hrgtests/HrgTestsApplicationTests.java:[5,47] package com.humanresources.game.model.territory does not exist
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Application 1.0-SNAPSHOT ........................... SUCCESS [  1.533 s]
[INFO] Model 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............................... SUCCESS [  5.104 s]
[INFO] Tests 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............................... FAILURE [  3.715 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.771 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-21T18:33:11+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project hrg-tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Fred/IdeaProjects/HumanResources/hrg-tests/src/test/java/com/humanresources/game/hrgtests/HrgTestsApplicationTests.java:[3,42] package com.humanresources.game.model.card does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Fred/IdeaProjects/HumanResources/hrg-tests/src/test/java/com/humanresources/game/hrgtests/HrgTestsApplicationTests.java:[4,47] package com.humanresources.game.model.territory does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Fred/IdeaProjects/HumanResources/hrg-tests/src/test/java/com/humanresources/game/hrgtests/HrgTestsApplicationTests.java:[5,47] package com.humanresources.game.model.territory does not exist
```

**See a screen capture after `mvn clean install` :**

[image]

Comment: Could you please add pom.xml content for the Tests and Model modules? The most important excerpts are <parent>, <packaging>, and <dependencies>. Could you also add the summary output of Maven execution?

Comment: @illya-kysil Thanx for taking time for me and sorry for late answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Diagnostics**

The output for the Maven execution contains the following lines for the `hrg-model`:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ hrg-model ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
```

The JAR artifact of `hrg-model` is not a usual library after that, but an executable JAR packaged as described in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#repackage)

That executable JAR is not suitable for consumption by a Java compiler - or compiler for any other JVM-based language for that matter.

---

**Solution**

Only the Maven module which represents the final executable artifact of the project should include the invocation of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Please note, that your project has no such module at the moment.

I would suggest:

- adding the new module with `hrg-app` as a parent and `hrg-model` as a dependency;
- moving the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` invocation from the `hrg-app` module to the new module.

You may check the official guide from Spring Boot - [Creating a Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) - for a step-by-step guide and explanation.

Comment: Thanx Illya, I'm gonna try this tonight after work ^^

Comment: You say that my project doesn't have any module that could be the final executable artifact. But the App module is dedicated to that role as it only contains the Main method class and nothing else.

So what should I do to make it play this role and thus avoid the creation of another module ?

Comment: Thanx a lot Illya. I've strictly followed the recipe and it's just working. I'm really wondering why the 'repackage' action was here and where did it come from (from SpringBoot itself I guess), but as u may see in my own POMs, it's hidden. Hope the best for you. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this plugin in your APPs pom.xml under plugins section of the XML's build element.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version><--your maven version--></version>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanx @melroy-dsouza, unfortunately it doesn't work (for me). I still have the same error "package XXX does not exist"