# Unable to use class from Custom Spring boot library

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin, github

**Goal**

I want to use a private repository as a library in other spring boot projects by hosting it as a [GitHub package](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry).

**Library project**

https://github.com/sagarnayak/privatecentralrepo

**Client Project**

https://github.com/sagarnayak/repoclientproject

**Steps To Reproduce**

the library project has a library001 module. this is what I want to use as a library for other projects.

In the library module pom file, I have added the repackage execution goal.

```
......
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
......
```

I want to use the module as a library and host it as a [private GitHub package](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry).

When I do the `mvnw deploy` in the library001 module this should create an exec jar and push to GitHub to use this library in other projects.
Github has this exec jar.

[image]

To use the jar in the client project I have added this as a dependency in the client project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sagar</groupId>
    <artifactId>libraray001</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>exec</classifier>
</dependency>
```

This gets the project into the external libraries part of the client project. and this has the class that I want to use in the library (TestModel001).

[image]

But when I try to import this into any classes that I want to use it can not resolve the import.

**How do I use the library project in this project?**

Comment: Did you tried to google how to retup github as maaven repo?

Comment: The Github project is successfully pulled to the implementing project. I don't think it has any issue with that. I think it has something to do with the setup that I have done in the library project or the implementing project.
@Antoniossss I have added a screenshot from the implementing project external libraries part. it has the library project.

Comment: `Library001` is a spring boot application which can not being used as a consumable lib...

Comment: Also having code in the root of your project where the packaging is `pom` will not work because a pom does not have code and it will not compiled etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise How can I use the spring boot project as a consumable library? I have already tried adding executions to the lib project.

https://github.com/sagarnayak/privatecentralrepo/blob/ce495547da6c8e29b4b9822d7662f51ab12d9459/libraray001/pom.xml#L49

To the library pom file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export packages and classes to a test module in a Java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66290945/how-to-export-packages-and-classes-to-a-test-module-in-a-java-app)

Comment: @IllyaKysil I have tried adding the repackage execution to the lib project. https://github.com/sagarnayak/privatecentralrepo/blob/ce495547da6c8e29b4b9822d7662f51ab12d9459/libraray001/pom.xml#L49 and this creates a exec jar. when I do the mvnw deploy to the github this push the exec jar to the repo. you can see this https://github.com/sagarnayak/privatecentralrepo/packages/1017970 . I use this in the client project using <classifier>exec</classifier> . But still unable to import the file from the lib project.

Comment: Have you tried commenting-out the line classifier `exec` when using `libraray001` dependency? When you need to import a library's class in your code I think the dependency should not have any classifier.

Comment: I have tried that the first time. It dint work so I added the exec.

Comment: The TestModel001 is not a java class. How do you want to use it?

Comment: Test Model is a kotlin class. The spring boot project is written in kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with this -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The issue was with the pom file.

I was using the configurations for an older version.

Answer (score 1):

You are packaging the library via `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

It produces a JAR that has a self-running spring boot structure, and so you are unable to import it as a library correctly.

Try to remove `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from your `libraray001` pom.xml, rebuild, republish and try to consume that artifact in your `client` project again, refreshing the dependencies and preferably bumping up the library version, to exclude caching possibility during the test.

Answer (score 0):

The client project as visible at [sagarnayak/repoclientproject](https://github.com/sagarnayak/repoclientproject/commit/317b8b1f84f6741e5736f9fb94dbccc5b131afcc) is not configured to consume the artifacts from the private Maven repository hosted on GitHub as described in the [Working with the Apache Maven registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages).

Specifically, following settings are missing:

- `<repositories>` configuration in `pom.xml`
- `<servers>` configuration in local `settings.xml`

Add following elements to the `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/sagarnayak/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Add following elements to the `settings.xml`

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>github</id>
        <username>sagarnayak</username>
        <password>YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**Note: Keep `settings.xml` local to your machine - don't leak that Personal Access Token!**

Comment: Hi
This is already configured in the .m2 settings.xml file. I am able to pull the code successfully to the client project.

Comment: Great to hear! Anyway, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: The issue is not that. The issue is that I am able to get the code from Github. but I am not able to import to my code.

Comment: Please check the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66307680/1091731